# How to sort the results in case sensitive manner in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, case-sensitive

I have a table with utf-8 strings in PostgresQL. When I add `ORDER BY` to a `SELECT` query, the results are ordered in case-insensitive manner, which seems odd:

```
AA
ab
ac
Am
At
```

How can I sort the results *case-sensitively*, i.e.

```
AA
Am
At
ab
ac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be converting as BYTEA

```
select  your_column 
from your_table  
order by  your_column::TEXT::BYTEA
```

Comment: what about negative values? for example: SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1, '-100'), (3, 'test'),(3, 'aes'), (1, '1'), (1, '-10'),(1, '-1'), ('1', '0.05'), (2, '2'),(1, '2.05'), (1, '2.4'), (1, '2.5')) AS t (num,name)
ORDER BY name::bytea puts negative values in the wrong order